# ERRO Linux Mint "Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc "

Tags: linux, obs-studio

i want to use virtual camera on linux with obs studio. i see this package https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink
i ran
`sudo apt install qtbase5-dev`
`sudo apt install libobs-dev`
`git clone --recursive https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio.git`
`git clone https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink.git cd obs-v4l2sink mkdir build && cd build cmake -DLIBOBS_INCLUDE_DIR="../../obs-studio/libobs" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..`

when i ran `cmake -DLIBOBS_INCLUDE_DIR="../../obs-studio/libobs" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..`
i got error
`-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
The C compiler

```
"/usr/bin/cc"
```

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

```
Change Dir: /home/arp/obs-v4l2sink/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_a18d3/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_a18d3.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_a18d3.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/arp/obs-v4l2sink/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_a18d3.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_a18d3.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /home/arp/obs-v4l2sink/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
Linking C executable cmTC_a18d3
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_a18d3.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc      CMakeFiles/cmTC_a18d3.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTC_a18d3 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_a18d3.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_a18d3] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/arp/obs-v4l2sink/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_a18d3/fast] Error 2
```

`CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project. Call Stack (most recent call first): CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)`

`CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project): No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.`

`Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.`

`-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/home/arp/obs-v4l2sink/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also "/home/arp/obs-v4l2sink/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".`

i have seen some articles. but nothing changes.

anyone can help me?

Comment: make sure you have at least version 3.15 or later of cmake

Comment: Mint 20 example https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wA3FhB3KFvVVE3A9WI0Qbo22QQL8vwQj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: cmake version 3.16.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake). @RAZ0229

Comment: @Knud i got same error when i ran `cmake ..`

Comment: @KnudLarsen i can't understand sorry

Comment: obs / obs-v4l2sink is C++ code, so please install the c++ compiler : `sudo apt install g++` . Besides that, the installed gcc cannot function with no g++. I.e. g++ dependencies will make gcc (cc) work fully.